# SQL Server Management Studio can connect but Powershell cannot

Tags: powershell, ssms

I'm a DBA and I'm trying to come up with a POWERSHELL script that can read a text file filled with SQL Server instance names, connect to those servers via POWERSHELL, poll said servers for information (most importantly their sql server version number) and export this information into another text file.

For the most part what I have come up with works fine as is, but the problem I'm currently running into is on some servers POWERSHELL cannot poll this information but yet I can connect up to those servers fine with SSMS.

The code that does most of the heavy lifting is:

`$sql_svr = new-object "microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server" $machine_name #$sql_instance;`

This code, when I hover over $sql_svr I get these results on a successful connection:
[image]

But if POWERSHELL cannot connect, the hover shows nothing.

What has to happen on the servers not connecting to allow POWERSHELL to get successful results?

Comment: Perhaps these are servers hosting multiple instances? Why is the `$sql_instance` variable commented out?

Comment: Test code left behind from the previous DBA that has since left the company.  Should I dig into that?
I checked for multiple instances on some of the "cannot connect" and they are all single instance servers.

Answer (score 1):

I happened to face this issue today in one of the server machine. Looks like it was the problem with latest "SqlServer"(>v22.0) module versions. When I downgraded the "SqlServer" module to v21.1.18218 it started to work.

Comment: Unfortunately downgrading isn't an option for us.  Also, this is happening to sql server versions between 2014 all the way to 2019.  We haven't started using 2022 yet.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was not clear. Can you try downgrading SqlServer powershell module which I believe you are using to connect to your SQL Servers through powershell.

`Uninstall-Module -Name SqlServer`
`Install-Module -Name SqlServer -RequiredVersion 21.1.18218`

Answer (score 0):

I worked with our Server team to determine it was a firewall port issue that needed addressed.  Some servers had their ports open originally by the server team when they were built and some servers did not.
Once the server team determined what ports needed opened up, everything started working.
Potential ports are 445 and 5985 or 5986.  I'm not sure what those are, but they created a Group Policy rule and once they ran it, I ran a GPUPDATE /force and then ran my remote PS script and it ran fine.